# Getting a reference to a Spinner in a Base Adapter

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

I have a BaseAdaptor that I have extended to handle some objects (Spinner, toggle view etc..). I am trying to get the selected value from the spinner. My problem is that the getSelectedItem() always returns the first value (index 0). Not sure what I am missing. Here is my code.

```
GridView grid=(GridView)findViewById(R.id.grdMain);
AcmObjectBaseAdaptor ad = (AcmObjectBaseAdaptor) grid.getAdapter();
String year = "";
if (ad.getItem(0) instanceof Spinner){
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) ad.getItem(0);
    year = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
    System.out.println("Selected: " + year);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add and onItemSelectedListener to the spinner?

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
         System.out.println("onItemSelected: " + position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {}
});
```